# Avoid SQL injection while inserting a mix of hard-coded and variable values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm writing database queries with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise). My tables look like this:

```
                                    Table "public.setting"
│ user_id          │ integer           │ not null                
│ visualisation_id │ integer           │ not null  
│ name             │ character varying │ not null                                  

                                    Table "public.visualisation"
│ visualisation_id │ integer           │ not null                
│ template_id      │ integer           │ not null
```

I want to insert some values into `setting` - three are hard-coded, and one I need to look up from `visualisation`.

The following statement does what I need, but must be vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
var q = "INSERT INTO setting (user_id, visualisation_id, template_id) (" +
        "SELECT $1, $2, template_id, $3 FROM visualisation WHERE id = $2)";
conn.query(q, [2, 54, 'foo']).then(data => {
    console.log(data); 
});
```

I'm aware I should be using [SQL names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names), but if I try using them as follows I get `TypeError: Invalid sql name: 2`:

```
var q = "INSERT INTO setting (user_id, visualisation_id, template_id) (" +
        "SELECT $1~, $2~, template_id, $3~ FROM visualisation WHERE id = $2)";
```

which I guess is not surprising since it's putting the `2` in double quotes, so SQL thinks it's a column name.

If I try rewriting the query to use `VALUES` I also get a syntax error:

```
var q = "INSERT INTO setting (user_id, visualisation_id, template_id) VALUES (" +
        "$1, $2, SELECT template_id FROM visualisation WHERE id = $2, $3)";
```

What's the best way to insert a mix of hard-coded and variable values, while avoiding SQL injection risks?

Comment: to use query as value, take it into brackets like a subquery, eg `"$1, $2, (SELECT template_id FROM visualisation WHERE id = $2), $3)"`

Comment: I think @VaoTsun is correct here. And SQL Names got nothing to do here, since you are not using dynamic column names.

Comment: Thanks both. In the first example, couldn't the user supply some SQL in place of `$1` and potentially achieve SQL injection, because the inner query uses dynamic column names? (I'm checking existing code for vulnerabilities.)

Comment: @Richard I don't think so, as `$1` represents a simple value. If you pass it any string, it will be properly escaped as a string, no injection will be possible.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! So in a query like `SELECT $1, $2, template_id, $3 FROM visualisation WHERE id = $2` there's no need to use SQL names? Why then are they needed at all?

Comment: @Richard you would need to use SQL Names there, in a simple SELECT. But your example is an INSERT that uses SELECT, which is a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine. I think you know value placeholders ($X parameter) and SQL Names too, but you are a bit confused.

In your query you only assign values to placeholders. The database driver will handle them for you, providing proper escaping and variable substitution.

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-prepare.html) says:

> When a parameter's data type is not specified or is declared as
>   unknown, the type is inferred from the context in which the parameter
>   is used (if possible).

I can't find a source that states what is the default type, but I think the INSERT statement provides enough context to identify the real types.

On the other hand you have to use [SQL Names](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) when you build your query dinamically. For example you have variable column or table names. They must be inserted through `$1~` or `$1:name` style parameters keeping you safe from injection attacks.